# Swift Create new array based on two arrays under certain conditions

Tags: swift

I need some help in order to establish a new array in Swift 2.0.

I have two arrays, one contains dates and the other payments at this date.

```
let year = [February 2016, March 2016, June 2017, October 2017, January 2018, April 2019] // Data at which a payment is initiated
let payment = ["1000","2000,"3000","1000","2000,"3000"] // payment amount at date in array year
```

I'd like to create two new arrays in Swift code based on this.
The final result should look like this:

```
let yearSum [2016, 2017, 2018,2019]  // only full year 
let paymentSum ["3000","4000","2000","3000"] // sum of all payment in the year
```

The array "yearSum" should contain only the full year number, while "paymentSum" should contain the sum of all payments in the year.

Has anybody an advice how I can code this?

Many thanks

Comment: What type is `year`? Is it `[NSDate]` or just `[String]`? Either way, I would use a dictionary instead like: `[Int: Double]`.

Comment: for payment sum you'll use paymentSum.reduce(0, combine: +) to get the sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The input

First of all let's assign good names to the input constants

```
let monthStrings = ["February 2016", "March 2016", "June 2017", "October 2017", "January 2018", "April 2019"]
let paymentStrings = ["1000", "2000", "3000", "1000", "2000", "3000"]
```

### What can go wrong

We are working with strings as input, so many things could go wrong during the parsing of a Date or of an Int. For clarity lets define the following enum

```
enum Error: ErrorType {
    case InputParamsHaveDifferentSizes(Int, Int)
    case FirstParamHasInvalidDate
    case SecondParamHasInvalidInt
}
```

### The function

```
func groupData(monthStrings: [String], paymentsStrings:[String]) throws -> [Int:Int] {
    // make sure both arrays have the same size
    guard monthStrings.count == paymentStrings.count
        else { throw Error.InputParamsHaveDifferentSizes(monthStrings.count, paymentStrings.count) }

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"

    // creates dates: an array of NSDate representing monthStrings
    // if dates has a different size of monthsString then throws and error
    guard
        case let dates = (monthStrings.flatMap { formatter.dateFromString($0) })
        where dates.count == monthStrings.count
        else { throw Error.FirstParamHasInvalidDate }

    // creates payments: an array of Int representing paymentsStrings
    // if payments has a different size of paymentsStrings then throws and error
    guard
        case let payments = (paymentStrings.flatMap { Int($0) })
        where payments.count == paymentStrings.count
        else { throw Error.SecondParamHasInvalidInt }

    // put togheter dates and payments and group the results by year
    return zip(dates, payments).reduce([Int:Int]()) { (var result, elm) -> [Int:Int] in
        let year = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Year], fromDate: elm.0).year
        result[year] = elm.1 + (result[year] ?? 0)
        return result
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let res = try groupData(monthStrings, paymentsStrings: paymentStrings)
print(res) // [2018: 2000, 2017: 4000, 2016: 3000, 2019: 3000]
```

### Update

In the comment below you say you need to access the keys by index and you need them sorted so

```
let sortedKeys = res.keys.sort()

func value(index:Int) -> String? {
    let key = sortedKeys[index]
    let value = res[key]
    return value
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for the quick response.   The reason why I'm using arrays instead of Dics is that I need to populate a Tableview with the results. To my understanding this is much easier with arrays than dictionaries, especially if the table view must show a sorted order. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, due to lack of response I'll just assume `years` is an array of strings:

```
// Data
let years = ["February 2016", "March 2016", "June 2017", "October 2017", "January 2018", "April 2019"]
let payed = ["1000", "2000", "3000", "1000", "2000", "3000"]

// Preparation    
var result: [String: Double] = [:]
let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet

// Results
let yearOnly = years.flatMap { $0.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(digits).filter { !$0.isEmpty } }
zip(yearOnly, payed).forEach { result[$0.0] = (result[$0.0] ?? 0) + (Double($0.1) ?? 0) }
```

Note that `yearOnly` is created by filtering out all non-digits, so if you'll have days inside of `years` then this won't work and you'll have to use another method to filter out the years.

```
// Output
["2018": 2000.0, "2019": 3000.0, "2016": 3000.0, "2017": 4000.0]
```